# How to compare text in Ranorex using C#?

Tags: c#, text, ranorex

How to compare text in Ranorex using C# ?
I wants to compare text from a website. In this case we have to compare the text.

Comment: http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/T_Ranorex_Validate.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the correct validation form of the string:

```
string validationHasToMatch = "Test data";
```

Add the element to the repository that contains the text needed for comparison. Let's call the repo object:

```
repo.DomObject.textElement;
```

Build a validation around them:

```
if (repo.DomObject.TextElement.InnerText == validationHasToMatch)
{
  Report.Success("Texts match!");
} else {
  Report.Failure("Texts don't match!");
}
```

This is just a quick example and a base to build more functionality ontop of.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use the innertext property on the element from the website.  So for instance use the xpath to find the element, get the innertext property and compare that text in c# the same way you would compare any other string